# Find average of two largest marks from three marks

Tags: php, mysql

I wish to get average of two highest marks from three series marks.

Here is the code that I tried:

```
if(isset($_POST['find'])){
    $a=$_POST['a'];
    $ins=mysql_query("SELECT * 
                      FROM test1
                      WHERE studid ='$a'
                      ORDER BY mark DESC 
                      LIMIT 2");
    while($r=mysql_fetch_row($ins)){
        echo $r[2];
    }
}
```

Comment: Please upgrade to `mysqli_` functions and use prepared statements with placeholders because your query is currently insecure.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it relates to deprecated code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query should be:

```
  -- studid=1 top two average marks
  SELECT AVG(A.mark) avgTop2Marks FROM
  (SELECT mark
  FROM test1
  WHERE studid=1
  ORDER BY mark DESC 
  LIMIT 2) A;

  -- studid=1 distinct top two average marks
  SELECT AVG(A.mark) avgDistinctTop2Marks FROM
  (SELECT DISTINCT mark
  FROM test1
  WHERE studid=1
  ORDER BY mark DESC 
  LIMIT 2) A;
```

Here is a [**DEMO on SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f5f2bb/4)